# Setting SPO Site Page to classic look

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

SharePoint Online Site Collection.  Classic UI, made via SP Admin.  I've created a page via the Cog --> Add a Page.  This has been dropped into the Site Pages directory.  Accessing the page gives it the new / modern UI, which I don't want.  Configurations checked are

1. Site Pages --> Site Settings --> Advanced Settings --> Set to Classic Experience
2. SPO Settings --> Have made sure that both OD4B and SPO settings are set to classic
3. Editing the page gives me no options to change the UI.  I've changed the content type from site page to a wiki page with no success
4. Checked the web part maintenance page for any options.  Nothing appears visible here.

Any ideas on how to change this is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't go back to the classic look of a Site Page in SharePoint Online. You'll have to use a Wiki Page to use the classic look.

[image]

Image from [How to bypass the new Modern Team Site Page experience](http://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-bypass-the-new-modern-team-site-page-experience/)

Answer (score 3):

Go to SPO settings > Site Pages, ensure that "prevent users from creating site pages" is set.

By default, its set to allow. Once you change this, you might need to wait for 24 hours to get the classic look back !

[image]

Using CSOM and powershell (need global admin rights) :

```
# Load SharePoint Online Client Components SDK Module
Import-Module 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll'

# Set script constants
$sitePagesFeatureIdString = 'B6917CB1-93A0-4B97-A84D-7CF49975D4EC'

# Set up client context
$userName = Read-Host "Username"
$password = Read-Host "Password" -AsSecureString
$siteUrl = Read-Host "Site Url"
$webUrl = Read-Host "Server-Relative Web Url"
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteUrl)
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $password)
$context.Credentials = $credentials

# Get the list of existing features
$web = $context.Site.OpenWeb($webUrl)
$features = $web.Features
$context.Load($features)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

# Verify that the Site Pages feature is present in the web
if(($features | ? { $_.DefinitionId -eq $sitePagesFeatureIdString }).Count -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "The Site Pages feature is already disabled in this web"
    return
}

# Remove the Site Pages feature from the web
$features.Remove((new-object 'System.Guid' $sitePagesFeatureIdString), $false)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

# Verify that the Site Pages feature is no longer present in the Web
$web = $context.Site.OpenWeb($webUrl)
$features = $web.Features
$context.Load($features)
$context.ExecuteQuery()
if(($features | ? { $_.DefinitionId -eq $sitePagesFeatureIdString }).Count -eq 0)
{
    Write-Host "The Site Pages feature has been successfully disabled"
}
else
{   
    throw "The Site Pages feature failed to be disabled"
}
```

reference - [Allow or prevent creation of modern site pages by end users](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Allow-or-prevent-creation-of-modern-site-pages-by-end-users-c41d9cc8-c5c0-46b4-8b87-ea66abc6e63b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Answer (score 0):

We can't go back to the classic look of a Site Page in SharePoint Online. You'll have to use a Wiki Page to use the classic look and then customize according to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

A few years later.... you can add "classic" type content types to the site pages library like web part page, basic page (and any page layout you created) and they'll appear in the "new" drop down and allow you to add classic pages in a modern site.